# Renaming multiple columns with dplyr rename(across(

Tags: r, dplyr, rename, across

Hey i'm trying to rename some columsn by adding "Last_" with the new version of dplyr but I keep getting this error

```
Error: `across()` must only be used inside dplyr verbs.
```

this is my code

```
data %>% rename(across(everything(), ~paste0("Last_", .)))
```

dplyr version: v1.0.2

Answer (score 69, accepted):

We can use `rename_with` instead of `rename`

```
library(dplyr)   
library(stringr)
data %>%
      rename_with(~str_c("Last_", .), everything())
```

Reproducible example

```
data(iris)
head(iris) %>% 
    rename_with(~str_c("Last_", .), .cols = everything())
#  Last_Sepal.Length Last_Sepal.Width Last_Petal.Length Last_Petal.Width Last_Species
#1               5.1              3.5               1.4              0.2       setosa
#2               4.9              3.0               1.4              0.2       setosa
#3               4.7              3.2               1.3              0.2       setosa
#4               4.6              3.1               1.5              0.2       setosa
#5               5.0              3.6               1.4              0.2       setosa
#6               5.4              3.9               1.7              0.4       setosa
```

---

According to `?rename`

> rename() changes the names of individual variables using new_name = old_name syntax; rename_with() renames columns using a function.

and in `?across`

> across() makes it easy to apply the same transformation to multiple
> columns, allowing you to use select() semantics inside in summarise()
> and mutate().

The description says its use within `mutate/summarise` (and `transmute`?), and no indication of usage with any other functions i.e. it would fail with `select`

Comment: thanks, but do you know if it's a problem with dplyr rename function or why it doens't work ?

Comment: @Ian.T it's just that `across` is used for transformation functions within `summarise/mutate/transmute`.  The functionality is not extended with `rename` (may be in the future, not sure because in each release they deprecate and introduce new functions).  It is possible though to make the `across` generalizable for each of the tidyverse functions.  In the current context, I guess `rename_with` is suitable for these cases

Answer (score 15):

From the `vignette('colwise')` (or see the [web version](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/colwise.html)).

> "across() doesn’t work with select() or rename() because they already use tidy select syntax; if you want to transform column names with a function, you can use rename_with()."